# How to call a method in another thread?

Tags: ios

I have a tableview. But when i scroll the table view my timer is stop at that time and again its call after scrolling.
so i want to call that timer in another thread.

```
 // This is my timer..

 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(Timer_Called) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

 // This is my another thread method. I am trying like this but its not working

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self Timer_Called];
  });
```

anybody can suggest me ?

Comment: What happens in `Timer_Called` (which BTW is an unconventional name)?

Comment: Same thing is happening. When i scroll the tableview the timer is stopped.

Comment: What does `Timer_Called` do?

Comment: please add Timer_Called code

Comment: -(void)Timer_Called
{
    stopWatch_count ++ ; // a variable for time increment
    int Min=stopWatch_count/3600;
    int Sec = (stopWatch_count%3600)/60;
    int MiliSec = (stopWatch_count%3600)%60;
    
    NSLog(@"Min == %d",Min);
    NSLog(@"Sec == %d",Sec);
    NSLog(@"MiliSec == %d",MiliSec);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTimer` usually don’t fire when the user is scrolling a table or other UIScrollView – or doing anything else that puts the run loop in event tracking mode.

When We define a timer like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(call_a_method:)
                               userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The timer is added in the default run loop mode that is `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. It means your timers will effectively be frozen when the default run loop mode is on hold.

If you need the timer running when you scroll your table view then do this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(Timer_Called)
                                         userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to tell him how to run a runloop on the non-main thread?